# How do I rewrite the URL for example.com/index.php#anchor to example.com/anchor?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a page (**example.com**) with anchors at major sections (**example.com/index.php#anchor**, **example.com/index.php#about**, **example.com/index.php#contact**, etc.) as well as subpages (**example.com/subpage.php**).

Here's my **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/my404page.php

RewriteRule ^anchor/?$ index.php#anchor [R,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^subpage/?$ subpage.php [NE,L]
```

The subpage rewrite rule works great.

For the anchor link, including the "**R**" (redirect) flag changes the URL to **example.com/index.php#anchor**, *but I want the URL to be **example.com/anchor***.

If I remove the **R** flag and enter **example.com/anchor** into my browser, than it goes to the index page and keeps the clean URL (example.com/anchor) *but doesn't scroll to the anchor*.

So... Is there any way to achieve this in .htaccess, or is there a good way to achieve this with JavaScript?

Comment: @zackify Why is "JavaScript" a bad tag for this question?

Comment: hashtag is client side can't be manipulated with mod_rewrite.

Comment: @Prix that what I've read, which apparently is why only the [R] redirect works... But I have yet to find a good solution on SO or anywhere else.

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript or even php which is why I took it out. If you were to do this with javascript it wouldn't be that hard to simply replace '#' with a '/' and then redirect to that url.

Comment: @zackify It looks like I'm looking to achieve this with JavaScript then. The reason I included the .htaccess code is because I wanted to show what I had tried. Can you elaborate on "simply replace '#' with a '/' and then redirect to that url"?

Comment: Your question does not have any javascript code for us to help you with though.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do that with URL rewrite. Because the browser scroll down when the `#` is part of the URL... not on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `.htaccess`. But you can do it with the following JavaScript code:

```
window.location = String.prototype.replace(window.location, /index\.php#(.*)/, function(match, g1){return g1;});
```